# My user name is not displayed when I launch the terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

When I open up the terminal, I get this instead of my username:

```
unknown-b8-8d-12-22-27-72%
```

Is there any reason why I am getting such username?

Comment: You should post your PS1 string from .bash_profile or .bashrc.  That will provide the necessary information for someone to help you out.

Comment: what does it say when you issue `whoami` on the prompt?

Comment: `whoami` does post my real username: `Malloc`

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fix this by defining your own `PS1` (your prompt) by editing the `~/.bashrc` config file. An example including your username, hostname, working directory and prompt sign is:

```
PS1='\u@\h \w \$ '
```

After editing `~/.bashrc` you need to source it to make the changes apply in the current shell:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```